Nodemailer is not working on DigitalOcean production, but work in local development . Using MailTrap , can't receive mail why
I check all of our .env file . There is nothing wrong I using MailTrap port 2525 .
And On DigitalOcean I use PM2 . Please tell me appropriate answer. I search all of the other but not satisfy and not working .
To solve this problem

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
